# FFTW Array Order in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fft, fftw

I'd like to use FFTW to compute the Fourier Harmonics for a 2D dataset.  And I think I'm getting the hang of it but I need to 'decipher' the complex output in terms of harmonics.  First here's my toy code:

```
PROGRAM FFTW_TEST
    USE, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding

    IMPLICIT NONE

    INTEGER :: i, j, n, m, l, k
    REAL    :: pi2, norm, norm2
    REAL(C_DOUBLE), POINTER, DIMENSION(:) :: theta, func
    COMPLEX(C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX), POINTER, DIMENSION(:) :: fmn_1d
    REAL(C_DOUBLE), POINTER, DIMENSION(:,:) :: func_2d, r_2d, i_2d
    COMPLEX(C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX), POINTER, DIMENSION(:,:) :: fmn_2d


    INCLUDE 'fftw3.f03'
    TYPE(C_PTR) :: plan
    TYPE(C_PTR) :: real_1d, complex_1d
    TYPE(C_PTR) :: real_2d, complex_2d

    pi2 = 8.0 * ATAN(1.0)

    !------ 1D Example
    n = 64
    real_1d = FFTW_ALLOC_REAL(INT(n,C_SIZE_T))
    complex_1d = FFTW_ALLOC_COMPLEX(INT(n,C_SIZE_T))
    CALL C_F_POINTER(real_1d, func, [n])
    CALL C_F_POINTER(complex_1d, fmn_1d, [n])
    ALLOCATE(theta(n))

    FORALL(i=1:n) theta(i) = DBLE(i-1)/DBLE(n)
    FORALL(i=1:n) func(i)  = 1.0+2.0*cos(2*pi2*theta(i))-3.0*cos(3*pi2*theta(i)) ! Even Values
!    FORALL(i=1:n) func(i)  = 0.0+2.0*sin(4*pi2*theta(i))-3.0*sin(5*pi2*theta(i)) ! Odd Values

    WRITE(401,*) func(1:n)
    CALL FLUSH(401)

    norm    = n/2
    norm2   = n
    plan = FFTW_PLAN_DFT_R2C_1D(n, func, fmn_1d, FFTW_ESTIMATE)
    CALL FFTW_EXECUTE_DFT_R2C(plan, func, fmn_1d)
    CALL FFTW_DESTROY_PLAN(plan)
    func = REAL(fmn_1d)/norm
    func(1) = 2*func(1)
    WRITE(402,*) func; CALL FLUSH(402)
    func = -AIMAG(fmn_1d)/norm
    func(1) = 2*func(1) ! note should be zero
    WRITE(403,*) func; CALL FLUSH(403)
    plan = FFTW_PLAN_DFT_C2R_1D(n, fmn_1d, func, FFTW_ESTIMATE)
    CALL FFTW_EXECUTE_DFT_C2R(plan, fmn_1d, func)
    CALL FFTW_DESTROY_PLAN(plan)
    WRITE(404,*) func/norm2; CALL FLUSH(404)

    CALL FFTW_FREE(real_1d)
    CALL FFTW_FREE(complex_1d)
    IF (ASSOCIATED(theta)) DEALLOCATE(theta)


    !-------   2D Example
    m=16
    n=8
    real_2d = FFTW_ALLOC_REAL(INT(m*n,C_SIZE_T))
    complex_2d = FFTW_ALLOC_COMPLEX(INT(m*n,C_SIZE_T))
    CALL C_F_POINTER(real_2d, func_2d, [m,n])
    CALL C_F_POINTER(complex_2d, fmn_2d, [m,n])
    PRINT *,LBOUND(func_2d,DIM=1)
    ALLOCATE(fmn_1d(m),r_2d(m,n),i_2d(m,n))
    func_2d = 0.5
    DO i = 1, m
       DO j = 1, n
          DO l = 0, 8
             DO k = -4,4
                func_2d(i,j) = func_2d(i,j) + (l*100+k) * cos(l*pi2*(i-1)/m + k*pi2*(j-1)/n)
             END DO
          END DO
       END DO
       WRITE(501,*) func_2d(i,1:n); CALL FLUSH(501)
    END DO

    ! Note in the m direction we read m=0,1,2,3,4...
    !      in the n direction we read n=0..nx/2,-nx/2+1...-1
    norm    = m*n/2
    norm2   = norm*2
    plan = FFTW_PLAN_DFT_R2C_2D(n, m, func_2d, fmn_2d, FFTW_ESTIMATE)
    CALL FFTW_EXECUTE_DFT_R2C(plan, func_2d, fmn_2d)
    CALL FFTW_DESTROY_PLAN(plan)
    r_2d = REAL(fmn_2d)/norm
    r_2d(1,1) = r_2d(1,1)/2
    DO i = 1, m
       WRITE(502,*) r_2d(i,1:n); CALL FLUSH(502)
    END DO
    i_2d = -AIMAG(fmn_2d)/norm
    i_2d(1,1) = i_2d(1,1)/2
    DO i = 1, m
       WRITE(503,*) i_2d(i,1:n); CALL FLUSH(503)
    END DO
    DO i = 1, m
       DO j = 1, n
          IF (abs(r_2d(i,j))>1.0E-5 .or. ABS(i_2d(i,j))>1.0E-5) &
       WRITE(6,*) i,j,r_2d(i,j),i_2d(i,j)
     END DO
    END DO
    plan = FFTW_PLAN_DFT_C2R_2D(n, m, fmn_2d, func_2d, FFTW_ESTIMATE)
    CALL FFTW_EXECUTE_DFT_C2R(plan, fmn_2d, func_2d)
    CALL FFTW_DESTROY_PLAN(plan)
    DO i = 1, m
       WRITE(504,*) func_2d(i,1:n)/norm2; CALL FLUSH(504)
    END DO

    CALL FFTW_FREE(real_2d)
    CALL FFTW_FREE(complex_2d)
    IF (ASSOCIATED(fmn_1d)) DEALLOCATE(fmn_1d)



END PROGRAM FFTW_TEST
```

Now I'd like to extract the harmonics of a function which looks like:
$A_{mn} \cos(m\theta+n\phi)$, where $\theta$ and $\phi$ are the real-space grid.  First, taking the real part of the complex array appears to be correct.  The harmonics seem correct for simple functions.  However, in the final test case it seems that the array has an odd ordering.  Here's the ordering

```
m/n
0/0 1/0 2/0 3/0 4/0 5/0 6/0 7/0 8/0 0/1 1/1 2/1 3/1 4/1 5/1 6/1
7/1 8/1 0/2 1/2 2/2 3/2 4/2 5/2 6/2 7/2 8/2 0/3 1/3 2/3 3/3 4/3
5/3 6/3 7/3 8/3 0/4 1/4 2/4 3/4 5/4 6/4 7/4 8/4 ?/? ?/? ?/? ?/?
```

For reference here's what I'd expect the ordering to look like:

```
m/n
0/0 1/0 2/0 3/0 4/0 5/0 6/0 7/0 8/0 -7/0 -6/0 -5/0 -4/0 -3/0 -2/0 -1/0
0/1 1/1 2/1 3/1 4/1 5/1 6/1 7/1 8/1 -7/1 -6/1 -5/1 -4/1 -3/1 -2/1 -1/1
0/2 1/2 2/2 3/2 4/2 5/2 6/2 7/2 8/2 -7/2 -6/2 -5/2 -4/2 -3/2 -2/2 -1/2
```

It seems like the code is just treating the array like a linear array.  But what what I can read in the FFTW documentation this should not be the case.  One dimension of the array should correspond to the transforms along one dimension and the other the other.  Thus in some sense we should be able to read off m and n harmonics.

Can someone explain how the complex array should be ordered in terms of harmonics and the proper normalizations?

Comment: Note that `pi2 = 8.0 * ATAN(1.0)` is not precise, it is only single (actually default) precision.

Comment: @VladimirF Good point but the issue here is not that the result of the FFT lacks accuracy but that the layout of data in the array is not as documented by the FFTW docs.  If I understand it correctly the array should run from [0,NX/2] then [-NX/2+1,-1] across one dimension of the array.  But clearly it appears to wrap around.  Also the array appears to be doing some packing.  I'd like to understand it so I can output the frequency information in terms of mode numbers.

Comment: But remember that what is nx in C is ny in Fortran.

Comment: @VladimirF That would only explain it if we were off by the nx,ny values but the arrays appear shifted by 2 (in a linear sense), and it doesn't explain the mode ordering.  I've tried playing around with how I pass the array indicies but I don't get a consistent result.